# Row indexing/subsetting with only part of a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following DataFrame and MultiIndex instances:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'x': [1,2,3]},
    index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
        [('a', 'p', 1), ('b', 'z', 3), ('a', 'q', 2)],
        names=['l1', 'l2', 'l3'],
    ),
)

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(
    [('a', 'q'), ('a', 'p')],
    names=['l1', 'l2'],
)
```

How do I subset `df` using `idx`? My naive attempt failed (Pandas v2.0.3) :

```py
df.loc[idx]
```

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (2,2) (3,) (2,2)
```

Ideally I'd get a nicer error message than that, but clearly `.loc` isn't meant to subset using a partial MultiIndex.

I came up with two workarounds, but they're both kind of ugly for various reasons:

```py
df.loc[
    pd.IndexSlice[tuple(idx.get_level_values(n) for n in idx.names if n in df.index.names)]
]
```

```py
df.join(pd.DataFrame({'y': 1}, index=idx)).drop('y')
```

Is there an idiomatic way to do this? Or is this ultimately a Pandas feature request?

Answer (score 0):

Since the levels are different, you need to filter on just those levels:

```py
idx_names = [name for name in df.index.names if name not in idx.names]
df.loc[df.index.droplevel(idx_names).isin(idx)]
          x
l1 l2 l3   
a  p  1   1
   q  2   3
```

Another option is with the [select](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.select.select) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/), you have to convert to a list of tuples though:

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
df.sort_index().select(rows=idx.tolist())
          x
l1 l2 l3   
a  q  2   3
   p  1   1
```

You could create a function to use for such cases (not rigorously tested):

```py
def index_isin(df_index, index):
    idx = [df_index.isin(values, level=level) 
           for level, values in 
           zip(index.names, index.levels)]
    return np.logical_and.reduce(idx)

df.loc[index_isin(df.index, idx)]

          x
l1 l2 l3   
a  p  1   1
   q  2   3
```